# Android data Binding produces "Source folders generated at wrong location"

Tags: android, data-binding, android-studio

Updated to Android Studio 1.3.1 and tried to configure dataBinding

Top level gradle file contains

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1'
}
```

Project gradle file contains

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.0'
```

but I'm getting following message

**Source folders generated at incorrect location**

```
Warning:Folder /Users/myname/workspace/discoveroom/android-client/Caldroid/build/data-binding-info/debug

Warning:Folder /Users/myname/workspace/discoveroom/android-client/DiscoveroomAndroidClient/build/data-binding-info/debug

Information:3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause
```

[image]

Comment: I get that too but decided to ignore it, since no harm is done.

Comment: I doubt it caused AS not to load the binding class sometimes.

Comment: Im also getting this error, since using setting dataBinding=true. Im using the gradle 1.5.0 which includes the plugin directly so didn't have to put that in... Im getting some errors when adding data variables to my xmls. Its saying it can't resolve the classes, and I'm wondering if its related to this...

Answer (score 1):

change

```
classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc4'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help. But it produces a new error - Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.databinding:adapters:1.0-rc3

Comment: I get this error when I try to switch to rc4: 
Error:Unable to find method 'android.databinding.tool.LayoutXmlProcessor.

Comment: any updates on this issue? i also get "Error:Unable to find method 'android.databinding.tool.LayoutXmlProcessor" when using rc4

Comment: Yes, it seems that the part of the plugin has changed, look at google developers at databinding, now it don't use classpath

Answer (score 0):

(Data Binding support appears to be changing *very* rapidly; you're going to find lots of outdated posts.)

In my toplevel build.gradle file, I have:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2+'
  }
}
```

There's no change to your app build.gradle file any more; ignore old posts talking about this kind of thing:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'  // OBSOLETE DO NOT USE
```

I'm using Android Studio 2.0 Preview 9.

In the Project Structure dialog box (Command - downarrow on a mac) make sure you're using Gradle 2.10.

Answer (score 0):

i did not change anything but add this code

```
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
}
```

in module build.gradle file;
it success.